# How to rbind new rows from one data frame to an existing data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, append, rbind

I would like to know how to append new data (rows) from one data frame, df2, to an existing data frame, df1, based on a unique value in each table. So I have an existing data frame, df1, that has historical data and each row has a unique value. I then pull data from the web and put it into a new data frame, df2. The new data frame also includes a unique value which may or may not match a unique value in df1.

I would like to take all rows in df2 that have a unique value that does not exist in df1, and append those rows to df1. My initial thoughts were to use code similar to this:

`ifelse(any(df1$unique_val==df2$unique_val), df1 <- df1, df1 <- rbind(df2, df1))`

But then I realized that I need a more one-to-one match than an "any" match. I know how I would do this in SQL with a UNION and WHERE clause, but I'm not sure how to make it work in R. The only related items I could find researching were appending all data from two data frames or appending a new column to an existing data frame.

The following example shows what I am looking for and why I am not looking to "join" these two data frames"

`df1 = data.frame(numb = c(1:6), rand = c(rep("Toaster",6)))`

`df1$unique_val <- paste0(df1$numb, df1$rand)`

`> df1
  numb  rand   unique_val
1    1 Toaster 1Toaster
2    2 Toaster 2Toaster
3    3 Toaster 3Toaster
4    4 Toaster 4Toaster
5    5 Toaster 5Toaster
6    6 Toaster 6Toaster`

`df2 = data.frame(numb = c(5:7), rand = c(rep("Toaster",2), c(rep("Radio",1))))`

`df2$unique_val <- paste0(df2$numb, df2$rand)`

`> df2
  numb  rand   unique_val
1    5 Toaster 5Toaster
2    6 Toaster 6Toaster
3    7   Radio   7Radio`

As you can see, row 3 in df2 is the only new row (a row that does not have a matching unique_val in df1). I would like to add this new row to df1. Note: it's not always the same row that is new in df2.

I used each of the joins from this post, [merge/join data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) as follows:

`merge(df1,df2, by = "unique_val")`

`merge(df1,df2, by = "unique_val", all = TRUE)`

`merge(df1,df2, by = "unique_val", all.x = TRUE)`

`merge(df1,df2, by = "unique_val", all.y = TRUE)`

I also tried the anti_join from dplyr:

`anti_join(df1,df2, by = "unique_val")`

Rbind gives me the following:

`rbind(df1,df2)
  numb    rand     conc
1    1 Toaster 1Toaster
2    2 Toaster 2Toaster
3    3 Toaster 3Toaster
4    4 Toaster 4Toaster
5    5 Toaster 5Toaster
6    6 Toaster 6Toaster
7    5 Toaster 5Toaster
8    6 Toaster 6Toaster
9    7   Radio   7Radio`

None of which give me the desired output of the following:

`numb    rand     conc
1    1 Toaster 1Toaster
2    2 Toaster 2Toaster
3    3 Toaster 3Toaster
4    4 Toaster 4Toaster
5    5 Toaster 5Toaster
6    6 Toaster 6Toaster
7    7   Radio   7Radio`

I'm looking to rbind these data frames, not join them.

Comment: What about using unique(rbind(df1,df2))???

Comment: Hi @Cath, @akrun solved my solution. I didn't ask the same question again--I provided much more detail as this website explains to do if you don't think it is a duplicate question, which I still do not believe it to be a duplicate. Fully read my question and use `merge(df1, df2, all.x=TRUE)`. It does NOT provide the solution I want to see as explained in my question.

Comment: @d84_n1nj4 Just do a full join: `merge(df1,df2,by=c('numb','rand'),all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)`

Comment: corecting: **outer** join, and the syntax can be simplified: `merge(df1,df2,by=c('numb','rand'),all=TRUE)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist/unique` from `data.table`.  We place the datasets in a `list`, use `rbindlist` (from `data.table`) to rbind the datasets in the `list` to a single `data.table` and get the `unique` rows with `unique` from `data.table` which also has the `by` option to specify the variable.

```
library(data.table)
unique(rbindlist(list(df1, df2)), by = "numb")
#   numb    rand unique_val
#1:    1 Toaster   1Toaster
#2:    2 Toaster   2Toaster
#3:    3 Toaster   3Toaster
#4:    4 Toaster   4Toaster
#5:    5 Toaster   5Toaster
#6:    6 Toaster   6Toaster
#7:    7   Radio     7Radio
```

Comment: Not my vote (and I won't vote here) but I think it could be related to [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255462/3627607). In my point of view your answer, albeit correct, is just dropping a bunch of function without any explanation on how it works/solve the problem. It make it not really useful for future readers as they'll have a hard time figuring what does what, so it's not useful **in my opinion** (and I assume in someone else opinion too).

Comment: You asked for an explanation, I just gave my point of view about it. I just added the precision because I can't speak for someone else.

Comment: The OP is way too long for me to read, but this may be relevant (since the same answer seems to fit): http://stackoverflow.com/q/39398135/ (Almost certainly not a dupe since the OP there wanted package-specific answers.)

Comment: @Frank That looks like a dupe.  I will tag it